# "/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid" no such file or directory

Tags: openvswitch

When I try to run `ovs-appctl command` I get this error:

```
2022-05-10T15:49:25Z|00001|daemon_unix|WARN|/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid: open: No such file or directory
```

ovs-appctl: cannot read pidfile "/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid" (No such file or directory)

How can I solve it? This file is not present in ovs filesystem